# Can't exec "/bin/sh": Argument list too long at perl

Tags: perl, tar

Below command in perl script is failing if there are many file in @file_to_tar, but it is working fine if we have less files in the array (@file_to_tar).

my $tar_command = "cd $ProcVars->{dropbox_dir}; tar -cvzf SmartMiles.$ProcVars->{batch_nb}.tar.gz -P @file_to_tar --remove-files";

Can some one please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is pass a very long list of files to `tar` is using the `--from-file` option:

```
tar -czf myarchive.tar.gz -P --from-file=$filelist --remove-files
```

You can also make it read the list of files from standard input by using `--from-file=-`

See https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/files.html for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much Bill for your suggestion. I did below and it is working now                      
my $file_location = "$ProcVars->{dropbox_dir}/Archive_Files.csv"; open(DATA, ">$file_location") or die $!; foreach $a (@file_to_tar) { print DATA "$a\n"; } close DATA; 

my $tar_command = "cd $ProcVars->{\dropbox_dir};tar -czf ABC.$ProcVars->{batch_nb}.tar.gz -P --files-from $file_location --remove-files";

Answer (score 3):

You might consider, rather than calling a shell command, using the Archive::Tar Perl module instead. In particular, the "[create_archive](https://perldoc.perl.org/Archive/Tar.html#Archive%3A%3ATar-%3Ecreate_archive(%24file%2C-%24compressed%2C-%40filelist))" method. This also would sidestep any potential problems arising from special characters or whitespace in the file names being interpreted by the shell your Perl code is invoking.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the reply. Archive::Tar is not available in our Perl-core common. So i used --from-file=$filelist  and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

it is working now.
my $file_location = "$ProcVars->{dropbox_dir}/Archive_Files.csv"; open(DATA, ">$file_location") or die $!; foreach $a (@file_to_tar) { print DATA "$a\n"; } close DATA;

my $tar_command = "cd $ProcVars->{\dropbox_dir};tar -czf ABC.$ProcVars->{batch_nb}.tar.gz -P --files-from $file_location --remove-files";